# EAS update not picking up environment variables for specified environment

Tags: expo, eas

I'm having trouble figuring out why `eas build` works as expected, however once I attempt to run `eas update`, my environment variables are set to those of my `development` profile.

My `eas.json`:

```
{
    "cli": {
        "version": ">= 5.9.0"
    },
    "build": {
        "development": {
            "channel": "development",
            "developmentClient": true,
            "distribution": "internal",
            "ios": {
                "simulator": true
            },
            "env": {
                "EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL": "http://123.45.678.90:8700/api",
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            }
        },
        "preview": {
            "channel": "preview",
            "distribution": "internal",
            "env": {
                "EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL": "https://example.com/api",
                "NODE_ENV": "production"
            }
        },
        "production": {
            "channel": "production",
            "extends": "preview",
            "distribution": "internal"
        }
    },
    "submit": {
        "production": {}
    }
}
```

When I run `eas build --profile preview --platform android`, and download the build, then my variables are correctly set. My `EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL` variable is correctly replaced with `https://example.com/api`.

However, if I then try to run `eas update`, it (for some reason), picks up my development configuration:

```
dotenv -e .env.preview -- eas update
```

After running this command, `EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL` points to `http://123.45.678.90:8700/api`.

The use of `dotenv-cli` here was taken from [this](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1265#issuecomment-1499987787) post.

Contents of `.env.preview`:

```
EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://example.com/api
NODE_ENV=production
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Use `--clear-cache` flag with `eas update`. I had the same problem. Should look like `dotenv -e .env.preview -- eas update --clear-cache`. The Expo/Metro cache is kept outside of the project files, and does not (always) detect env vars changes.